# Tensorflow: shape must be rank 5 but is rank 1 for 'conv3D'

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as tf
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        inputs = np.zeros([5,10,10,10,3])
        print(inputs)
        outputs = tf.nn.conv3d(
            input=inputs,
            filter=[5, 5, 5, 3, 8],  # filter:[filter_depth, filter_height, file_width, in_channels, out_channels]
            strides=[1, 4, 4, 4, 1],
            padding='SAME'
        )
        # outputs = get_model(inputs, True)
        print(outputs)
```

When I run the plain code in pycharm, it return the error information:

```
ValueError: shape must be rank 5 but is rank 1 for 'conv3D'(op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes: [5,10,10,10,3],[5].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring the link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv3d the filter should be a tensor, to be specific a variable (trainable), so change the `filter=[5, 5, 5, 3, 8]` to `filter=tf.get_variable(shape=[5, 5, 5, 3, 8], dtype=tf.float64, name='filter')` then run it and should work.